# How to find the correct OpenSSL EVP key length for DES3 encryption

Tags: encryption, openssl, rsa, des

I'm trying to implement a [hybrid cryptosystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) (**RSA** for key envelope, and **DES3 (with two-key option**) for data envelope). Thus, I'm trying first to implement DES3 with Openssl's `EVP` functions. Because it seems I can easily use EVP to combine RSA and DES3 encryption.

I've got this example code (changed data types to fix gcc warnings and put snippets in one file) from the Openssl book:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>

unsigned char *encrypt_example(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *data, int inl, int *rb);
unsigned char *decrypt_example(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *ct, int inl);
void select_random_key(unsigned char *key, int b);
void select_random_iv(unsigned char *iv, int b);
int seed_prng(int bytes);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);

    unsigned char key[EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH];
    unsigned char iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];
    unsigned char *ct, *out;
    unsigned char final[EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH];
    unsigned char str[] = "123456789abcdef";
    int i = 0;

    if (!seed_prng(16))
    {
        printf("Fatal Error! Unable to seed the PRNG!\n");
        abort();
    }

    select_random_key(key, EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH);
    select_random_iv(iv, EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH);


    /* EVP_des_ede3()       :three-key DES3 with ECB
     * EVP_des_ede()        :two-key DES3 with ECB
     * EVP_des_ede_cbc()    :two-key DES3 with CBC 
     * EVP_des_ede3_cbc()   :three-key DES3 with CBC */

    EVP_EncryptInit(&ctx, EVP_des_ede_cbc(), key, NULL);
    ct = encrypt_example(&ctx, str, strlen((const char*)str), &i);
    printf("Ciphertext is %d bytes.\n", i);

    EVP_DecryptInit(&ctx, EVP_des_ede_cbc(), key, NULL);
    out = decrypt_example(&ctx, ct, 8);
    printf("Decrypted: >>%s<<\n", out);
    out = decrypt_example(&ctx, ct + 8, 8);
    printf("Decrypted: >>%s<<\n", out);

    if (!EVP_DecryptFinal(&ctx, final, &i))
    {
        printf("Padding incorrect.\n");
        abort();
    }

    final[i] = 0;
    printf("Decrypted: >>%s<<\n", final);
    return 0;
}

int seed_prng(int bytes)
{
    if (!RAND_load_file("/dev/random", bytes))
        return 0;
    return 1;
}

void select_random_key(unsigned char *key, int b)
{
    int i;

    RAND_bytes(key, b);
    for (i = 0; i < b - 1; i++)
        printf("%02X:",key[i]);
    printf("%02X\n\n", key[b - 1]);
}

void select_random_iv (unsigned char *iv, int b)
{
    RAND_pseudo_bytes (iv, b);
}

unsigned char *encrypt_example(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *data, int inl, int *rb)
{
    unsigned char *ret = (unsigned char *)malloc(inl + EVP_CIPHER_CTX_block_size(ctx));
    int i, tmp, ol;

    ol = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < inl /100; i++)
    {
        EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, &ret[ol], &tmp, &data[ol], 100);
        ol += tmp;
    }

    if (inl % 100)
    {
        EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, &ret[ol], &tmp, &data[ol], inl%100);
        ol += tmp;
    }

    EVP_EncryptFinal(ctx, &ret[ol], &tmp);
    *rb = ol + tmp;
    return ret;
}

unsigned char *decrypt_example(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *ct, int inl)
{

    /* We're going to null-terminate the plaintext under the assumption it's
     * non-null terminated ASCII text. The null can be ignored otherwise.
     */
    unsigned char *pt = (unsigned char *)malloc(inl + EVP_CIPHER_CTX_block_size(ctx) + 1);
    int ol;

    EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, pt, &ol, ct, inl);
    if (!ol) /* there's no block to decrypt */
    {
        free(pt);
        return NULL;
    }

    pt[ol] = 0;
    return pt;
}
```

I'm compiling it with this

```
gcc -g -O0 -Wall evp_encrypt_decrypt.c  -o evp_encrypt_decrypt -lssl -lcrypto
```

Now if I execute this i get this output:

```
13:98:EB:64:D5:8B:1E:0A:70:1D:28:9D:25:3A:13:40:FE:C1:81:3C:C5:8F:4B:F6:66:1A:07:F8:17:D6:10:B6:4E:BC:45:96:00:A1:9F:59:44:A0:43:D9:9D:DD:C8:A9:0B:22:EC:7B:F2:5F:78:01:D1:58:6D:0B:B4:CB:5F:CD 

Ciphertext is 16 bytes.
Decrypted: >>(null)<<
Decrypted: >>12345678<<
Decrypted: >>9abcdef<<
```

Here it says that the the chipertext is 16 bytes (which is ok). But the key itself(hex code printed above) is **64 bytes long!**

However, DES3 with two-key options should have key length with 128 bits (including parity bits). However the **EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH** definition is by default **64**. Also I've tried to print  the chiper key length, the size of variable `key` and the ctx key size as seen below:

```
printf("Key length DES3: %d\n", EVP_CIPHER_key_length(EVP_des_ede3_cbc()));
printf("Key size: %d\n", sizeof(key));
printf("Cipher CTX key length: %d\n\n", EVP_CIPHER_CTX_key_length(&ctx));
```

This will output:

```
Key length DES3: 24
Key size: 64
Cipher CTX key length: 16
```

I'm a little bit confused here. Shouldn't be the DES3(two-key) key size 128 bits? Why is the length of DES3 key printed as 24(is this bit,byte,etc..)? Why are all these key lengths and sizes different?

Comment: I'm don't understand you confusion. You printed `EVP_CIPHER_key_length(EVP_des_ede3_cbc())` which is the *3 key triple des cipher*, so it should be 24. Your `key` array has 64 bytes because that is how big *you* made it.

Comment: @GregS The key is 64 byte ok, but why is the length of `EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH` 64 when there are key lengths of 192 bit like DES3 ?

Comment: That is simply the maximum key length that openssl supports for *any* cipher. It is a very simple convenience constant to allow the programmer to statically allocate memory for keys.

Comment: @GregS then for DES3 I can simple use 24 instead of EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH? I mean do I have to use EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH? Also DES3 takes three keys, each one 64 bit(with parity), then if I seed the function with 24 bytes, will it split it intro three parts? I'm really confused with all these key sized and how Openssl handle it.

Comment: Yes, you can just use 24 instead of EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH. Under the hood DES3 creates 3 keys, each with 64 bits, but if you use the EVP interface you don't have to worry about that detail. All that magic is encapsulated in the EVP_CIPHER_CTX.

Comment: @GregS you mean if I seed a key with 64 bytes, or 30 bytes.. It will only uses 24 bytes of this key? I already creating a key, is this key different from the used key for the DES3?

Comment: Yes, no matter how many bytes you allocate for your `key` array the DES3 will only use the first 24. The key you provide to `EVP_EncryptInit` is used, but it is further processed to create a larger table of per-round key data according to the DES key schedule, and this table is stored in the cipher context. This is done for performance. As I stated these details are not something you need to worry about. After `EVP_EncryptInit` has finished you can reuse or clean up your key array since a copy of it is made in the cipher context.

Comment: Just bike shedding: 2-key 3DES provides about 80-bits of theoretical security. Its equivalent to SHA1's theoretical security level. You should probably be using something a little larger in 2012/2014. 3-key 3DES (112-bits) and AES (128-bits) would be good choices.

Answer (score 0):

> However, DES3 with two-key options should have key length with 128 bits (including parity bits)

Yes. 2-key 3DES has a key size of 64x2 = 128-bits; and 3-key 3DES has a key size of 64x3 = 192-bits (as Greg S stated).

> However the EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH definition is by default 64

That's the maximum it can be (for all EVP symmetric ciphers), and not just DES/3DES/AES, etc. That value might even change in the future.

> Shouldn't be the DES3 (two-key) key size 128 bits?

Yes.

> Why is the length of DES3 key printed as 24 (is this bit, byte, etc..)?

Who knows.... but its in bytes, not bits.

> Why are all these key lengths and sizes different?

The size is based on the algorithm or cryptosystem.

2-key 3DES performs Encrypt-Decrypt-Encrypt and uses two keys. So one of the keys is used twice. 3-key 3DES performs Encrypt-Decrypt-Encrypt and uses three independent keys. That's how they were designed.

Comment: Will the EVP interface use key's 1-64 bit for 3des' key1, 65-128 for key2 and 129-192 for key3?